# Could every weird number be proven to be weird by iterating the following map?

Tags: number-theory

> **Question**: Could every weird number be proven to be weird by iterating the following map?

A weird number is an abundant number that is not pseudoperfect (i.e., not the sum of any subset of its proper divisors). For example, $70$ and $836$ are weird numbers.

Define a map $f$ from the set of all pairs $(S, m)$ where $S$ is a finite subset of the positive integers and $m$ is an integer (possibly zero or negative) to itself by the formula $f(S,m)=(S \cap [1, \Sigma{S}-m],\Sigma{S}-m)$ (where the $[]$ notation means a closed interval, not an LCM).

Then, given any weird number $n$, does iterating $f$ on $(\{$proper divisors of $n\}, n)$ always eventually lead to a pair $(S, m)$ for which $\Sigma{S} < m$?

The converse (namely, if iterating $f$ on $(\{$proper divisors of $n\}, n)$ eventually leads to a pair $(S, m)$ for which $\Sigma{S} < m$, then $n$ is not pseudoperfect) is easily proven to be true, as a special case of the following fact (which could be proven by induction on the number of iterations).

> **Fact**: If iterating $f$ on $(S, m)$ eventually leads to a pair $(S', m')$ for which $\Sigma{S'} < m'$, then $m$ is not the sum of any subset of $S$.

For most weird numbers $n$, the sum of all divisors of $n$ less than the abundance $\sigma(n)-2n$ (where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all divisors of $n$) is still less than the abundance (and conversely, if the sum of all divisors of an abundant number less than or equal to the abundance is still less than the abundance, then the abundant number must be weird). This means that just one iteration of $f$ is enough to prove that $n$ is weird.

However, for the weird numbers in the OEIS sequence [A100696](https://oeis.org/A100696), more than one iteration of $f$ is needed.

For example, consider the weird number $9272$. Its abundance is $56$, but the sum of all of its divisors less than $56$ is $72>56$, so the weirdness of $9272$ is not clear at first. However, $72-56=16$, and the sum of all divisors of $9272$ less than or equal to $16$ is $15<16$, so $9272$ is a weird number that requires two iterations of $f$ to prove its weirdness.